# Add post in my site without refresh in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page that inserts a new post in site like facebook wall.

I can add new post in my site, but when I insert it, the site will refresh.

What I need is, when I insert a new post, it is added to the page without refreshing the whole page.

**My Controller :-**

```
<?php



if (!defined('BASEPATH'))

    exit('No direct script access allowed');



class MyAccount extends MY_Controller {



    var $data;
    var $errors;




    function __construct() {



        parent::__construct();

        $this->template->title('Home');



        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            redirect('./home');
        }
        else {$this->template->set_layout('myaccount');}




    }





    public function index() {

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            redirect('./home');
        }
        else {$user = new User($_SESSION['user_id']);}


        $user = new User($_SESSION['user_id']);

        if($this->input->post()){



            $user->username = $this->input->post('name');
            $user->address = $this->input->post('address');
            $user->phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $user->skype = $this->input->post('skype');
            $user->facebook = $this->input->post('facebook');
            $user->mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
            $user->tall = $this->input->post('tall');
            $user->fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
            $user->wieght = $this->input->post('wieght');
            $user->fittnes = $this->input->post('fittnes');
            $user->fat = $this->input->post('fat');
            $user->email = $this->input->post('email');
            $user->birthdate = $this->input->post('birthdate');
            $user->gender = $this->input->post('gender');
            if(strlen($_FILES['pic']['name']) > 0){
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';
                $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pic'))
                {
                    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    if(is_array($error)){
                        foreach($error as $er){
                            $this->errors[] =$er;
                        }
                    }else{
                         $this->errors[] =$error;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $updata =$this->upload->data();
                    $imagePath = './uploads/'.$user->pic;
                    if(file_exists($imagePath)){
                         @unlink($imagePath);
                    }
                    $user->pic = $updata['raw_name'].$updata['file_ext'];
                }
        }


            if($this->input->post('password') == $this->input->post('confirm')){

                $user->password=md5(sha1(sha1($this->input->post('password'))));

                $user->save();

                $this->data['success'] = "Done";
            }else{
                $this->errors[] = "Error";

            }
        }



        $this->data['user'] = $user;

        $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;



       $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');

        $this->template->build('edit_profile',$this->data);



    }


    public function activate(){
        $this->template->set_layout('inner');

        if($_SESSION['is_verefied'] == 1){
            $this->data['status'] = "verified";
            $this->template->build('verefication_resend',$this->data);
        }else
        $this->template->build('activate',$this->data);
    }



    public function do_activate(){

        $code = $this->input->post('code',TRUE);
        $code  = strtolower($code);
        $user = new User();
        $user->where('id',$_SESSION['user_id'])->get();

        if(strtolower($user->code) ==  strtolower($code)){
            $user->active = 1;
            $user->save();
            echo 1;
            $_SESSION['is_verefied'] = 1;

        }else
        echo 0;

    }


        public function profile($user_id) {

        $check  = new User();
        $ex = $check->where('id',$user_id)->count();
        if( $ex == 0){ redirect('./home'); }
        else {
        $user = new User($user_id);


/************************************** Post *******************************************************************/
        $this->load->model('blog');

        if(isset($_POST['post'])){
        if(strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) 
        {
        $pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');

        if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){$type="image";} else {$type="image-with-text";}
        }

        else {$pic = ""; $type = "text"; }

            $result = $this->blog->addPost($_SESSION['user_id'], $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $result = $this->blog->getPost($user_id, 0 , 10);
        $this->template->build("profile" , array("response"=>$result));     
        }
        else{
        $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
        }


        $this->data['user'] = $user;
        $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
        $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
        $this->template->build('profile',$this->data);


        }
    }

        public function deletePostInProfile($ev_id) {

        $this->load->model('blog');
        $result = $this->blog->deletePost($ev_id);
        redirect('myaccount/profile/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'');


    }   

        public function insertComment($ev_id) {

            $data['co_comment'] = $this->input->post('comment');
            $data['co_postid'] = $ev_id;
            $data['co_userid'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $data['co_date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $this->load->model('blog');
            $insert = $this->blog->insertCommentToDB($data);

            if ($insert) {
                //get the last entry data
                $content = $this->blog->getComment($ev_id);
                $this->template->build("profile" , array("commentre"=>$content));
            }
        }


}
```

**View:-**

```
   <div id="inner-page-my-account">

<?php

    if(isset($success)){ ?>

    <div class="alert alert-success normal-alert" style="display: block;" id="okmsg">

        <p><span class="ico-text ico-alert-success" ></span><?= $success; ?></p>

    </div>
<?php

}



            if(isset($errors)){ ?>

            <div class="alert alert-error normal-alert" style="display: block;" id="notokmsg">

                <div><span class="ico-text ico-alert-error"></span>



            <?php

                if(count($errors) >0){

                    ?>

                        <ul>

                            <?php

                                foreach($errors as $error){

                                    echo "<li>$error</li>";

                                }

                            ?>

                        </ul>

                    <?php

                }

            ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <?php  } ?>

<div id="followbox" style="display:none" class="alert alert-success normal-alert">
<div id="show_message"></div>
</div>

        <div class="profile">
        <div class="rightprofile">
        <? if(isset($user->pic)) {?>
        <div class="picprofile"><img src="uploads/<?=$user->pic?>" width="250px" height="274px" /></div>
        <? } else { ?>
        <div><div id="Up-img"></div></div>
        <? } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="leftprofile">
        <div class="box-title-profile">

        <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($user->id != $_SESSION['user_id']) ){ ?>
        <div style="margin:auto">

        <div  style="float:right;padding-top:5px;"><?php if(isset($user->fullname)) echo $user->fullname; ?></div>


            <div style="float:left"><?
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from follow where fo_user_id_follow = '".$user->id."' and fo_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");
            if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) == '0'){
        ?>
            <input type="button" id="followme" class="followme" value="متابعة" onClick="followuser('<?=$user->id;?>' , 'followme');">
            <? } else { ?>
            <input type="button" id="followme" class="followme" value="إلغاء المتابعة" onClick="nofollowuser('<?=$user->id;?>' , 'nofollowme');">
            <?  } ?></div>


        </div>
        <? } ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">العمـــــــــــــــــــــــــر :</div><div class="infoleft">30 سنة</div>
        </div>        
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">الوزن المثـــــالي :</div><div class="infoleft"><?php if(isset($user->wieght)) echo $user->wieght; ?> كيلو</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">عضو مجموعــة :</div><div class="infoleft">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">الوزن المبدئــــي :</div><div class="infoleft"><?php if(isset($user->wieght)) echo $user->wieght; ?> كيلو</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">الوزن الحالــــــــي :</div><div class="infoleft"><?php if(isset($user->wieght)) echo $user->wieght; ?> كيلو</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="inforight">نسبة الدهـــــون :</div><div class="infoleft"><?php if(isset($user->fat)) echo $user->fat; ?>%</div>
        </div>
        <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($user->id == $_SESSION['user_id']) ){ ?>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="editinfo"><a href="./myaccount/" >تعديل بياناتي</a></div>
        </div>
        <? }?>                      
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="follow">
        <div class="followbox"><span class="black" >350</span> <br /> أتابع</div>
        <div class="followbox"><span class="black" >350</span> <br /> متابعيني</div>
        <div class="followbox"><span class="green" >- 201</span> <br /> سعرات مفقودة</div>
        <div class="followboxlast"><span class="red" >+ 325</span> <br /> سعرات موفرة</div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="wight"><img src="images/wight.png" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<? if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ?>
<div class="acceptlisttitle">مـــاذا تعمل الان</div>
<div class="clear"></div>        

<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($user->id == $_SESSION['user_id']) ){ ?>
<div id="postprofile">
<div id="massge" style="float:right">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('myaccount/profile/'.$user->id.'')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="upimgstatus">

</div>
<div class="textstatus">
<input id="inputUpProfile" name="inputUpProfile" class="inputUpProfile hidefile" type="file" />
<input type="button" id="PicUpProfile" class="sentpic" value="اضافة صورة">

<input name="post" type="text" id="textprofile" placeholder="اكتب رسالتك هنا ...">
<input type="submit" id="sent" name="sent" value="إرسال"> 
</div>
</form>
</div>
<? } ?>

<div style="clear: both"></div>

<ol class="timeline2 clear">
  <li class="spine">

  </li>

  <?php 
  $counter=0;
  //print_r($response);
  foreach ($response as $row) { 
  if($counter % 2 == 0){$class= "left";} else $class="right";
  ?>

   <li class="<?=$class ?>">
    <i class="pointer"></i>
    <div class="unit">

      <!-- Story -->
      <div class="storyUnit">
        <div class="imageUnit">
         <? if (empty($row->pic)) { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="images/nopic.png"></a>
          <? } else  { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="uploads/<?php echo $row->pic; ?>"></a>
          <div id="delpost" style="float:left">
          <a href="./myaccount/deletePostInProfile/<?=$row->ev_id;?>" id="deletepost">X</a>
          </div>
          <? } ?>
          <div class="imageUnit-content">
            <h4><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row->ev_date ?></p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <p> <?php echo $row->ev_text; ?><br />
        <? if (!empty($row->ev_pic)) { ?>
        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row->ev_pic ?>" width="250" height="250"</p>
        <? } ?></p>

      </div>
      <!-- / Story -->

      <!-- Units -->
      <ol class="storyActions">
<?
$selectComment = mysql_query("select * from comment,users where 
comment.co_postid = '".$row->ev_id."'
and comment.co_userid = users.id ");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectComment)){
?>
      <div id="resultcomment1"></div>
      <div id="resultcomment">
      <a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
      <img src="uploads/<?=$rows["pic"];?>" width="32" height="32" class="rightc" />
      </a>
      <b><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?=$rows["fullname"]; ?></a></b>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span><?=$rows["co_comment"]; ?></span>
      <br />
      <span class="commentdate"><?=$rows["co_date"]; ?></span></br></div>
<? } ?>      

      <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" size="41" />
       <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="add_comment()">ارسل</button>
       </form>

      </ol>
      <!-- / Units -->

    </div>
  </li>

   <?php $counter++; } ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</ol>

<? } ?>

</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


            function add_comment() {

                //get input data as a array
                var post_data = {
                    'comment': $("#comment").val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myaccount/insertComment/<?=$row->ev_id;?>",
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(comment) {
                        // return success message to the id='result' position
                        $("#resultcomment1").html(comment);
                    }
                });



        }
    </script>
```

** here i send comment but its show me error **

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/profile.php
```

and its load all site ,,, i need only after click send add comment to database and return the name and comment

Comment: this is way too general a question. You need to try your hand at some ajax and try SO when ur stuck somwhere. For starters, try to make an action, where you pass just the posts(formatted html), and not the rest of the layout. Then fetch this using ajax and replace your posts section with this data when you need to refresh

Comment: Need to use AJAX to post data to server without refreshing the form. You can use Jquery for this.

Comment: so how can do that, any help or example for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have lots of data in you controller and model. I don't want to handle that this time. But I want to share with you a sample of How to insert data in DB and then show the given data in your site without refresh page in CodeIgniter. I think this will be helpful.

Here is sample view -

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <table align="center">

            <tr>
                <td>Message :</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write here the message"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="result"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

Here is the controller -

```
/*
* this is just to load you view page call test.php from your view folder (Which is my given view file)
*/ 

public function test() {
    $this->load->view('test');
}

 /*
 * this is for insert data via Ajax and get the data
 */

public function insertByajax() {

    $data['message'] = $this->input->post('message');

    $insert = $this->YOURMODEL_NAME->insertDataToDB($data);

    if ($insert) {
        //get the last entry data
        $content = $this->YOURMODEL_NAME->getLastEnrtyData();
        echo $content->message;
    }
}
```

The model file -

```
/*
* Insert data to the content table
*/
public function insertDataToDB($data) {
    return $this->db->insert('content', $data);
}


/*
* Get the Inserted data from content table
*/
public function getLastEnrtyData() {
    $this->db->from('content');
    $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->where('id', $last_id);

    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

And now here is the most charming Javascript code - Just added this at the end of the view file

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#submit').click(function() {

                //get input data as a array
                var post_data = {
                    'message': $("#message").val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>YOUR_CONTROLLER/insertByajax",
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(message) {
                        // return success message to the id='result' position
                        $("#result").html(message);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

And here is my used Mysql table -

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `message` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So try this. Hope work and helpful for you. And let me know what's going on.

Comment: thank you but when click in submit its not do any think ?? why

Comment: Plz tell me full error. However I think you face problem from csrf protection.

Do the following thing in the config file

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'YOUR_COKIE_NAME';

Comment: thank now i add in database but i canot get the result to id result why ??

Comment: check my given controller function.

$content = $this->YOURMODEL_NAME->getLastEnrtyData();
echo $content->message; This message shown in the <td id="result"> </td> section. Also check you model getLastEnrtyData() function.

Comment: i need to show all data from table and show the last meesage i added same as facebook comment in status when you open status you show all comment and when you add new comment you show all comment with your comment

Comment: Ok. Done. I re-arrange the code. Check the following URL. View file - http://pastebin.com/fCSNrS3z . Controller - http://pastebin.com/EFJCAV06 . Model - http://pastebin.com/LAVhv0L6 . And let me know; What's going on.

Comment: thankx alot but if i have another post how can get the comment of it :)

Comment: Thats great! If my answer is works accept it. For another comment use the same technique hope works. Try this out.

Comment: i will have problem in delete by jquery can you help me

Comment: You can post question/problem with details code. Then the stackoverflow community people are able to see what's the problem. Hope you get help from here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351042/refresh-page-after-delete-by-jquery-in-codeigniter?comment=yes+its+work+in+browser+but+i+see+500+Internal+Server+Error

Comment: i will try your code and add some thing in my code but not work why ??

Comment: What's error you have got? I think you mismatch your code with my code.

Comment: i need now get message and username from database not only message

Comment: Your message and id are exists in the same table. So when you get the message; here you also get the id. Just catch the id and use update query with the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: function(res){
      // do stuff
   },
});
```

here is the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

I hope it will help to start with jquery post or get