# refresh page after delete by jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php

i have view that get all post from database like this :-

```
<ol class="timeline2 clear">
  <li class="spine">

  </li>

  <?php 
  $counter=0;
  foreach ($response as $row) { 
  if($counter % 2 == 0){$class= "left";} else $class="right";
  ?>

   <li class="<?=$class ?>">
    <i class="pointer"></i>
    <div class="unit">

      <!-- Story -->
      <div class="storyUnit">
        <div class="imageUnit">
         <? if (empty($row->pic)) { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="images/nopic.png"></a>
          <? } else  { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="uploads/<?php echo $row->pic; ?>"></a>
          <div id="delpost" style="float:left"><a href="#" id="deletepost" onClick="delete_post('<?=$row->ev_id;?>');">X</a></div>
          <? } ?>
          <div class="imageUnit-content">
            <h4><a href="./home/myaccount/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row->ev_date ?></p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <p> <?php echo $row->ev_text; ?><br />
        <? if (!empty($row->ev_pic)) { ?>
        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row->ev_pic ?>" width="250" height="250"</p>
        <? } ?></p>

      </div>
      <!-- / Story -->

      <!-- Units -->
      <ol class="storyActions">


      </ol>
      <!-- / Units -->

    </div>
  </li>

   <?php $counter++; } ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</ol>
```

then i wont to delete any post, so i click in :-

```
<div id="delpost" style="float:left"><a href="#" id="deletepost" onClick="delete_post('<?=$row->ev_id;?>');">X</a></div>
```

the function `delete_post` is jquery that call controller to delete post :-

```
function delete_post( ev_id )
{   
    var message_confirm =confirm("are you sure?");
    if (message_confirm==true)
       {
    $.ajax({
        url: "home/deletePostInProfile",
        type: "POST",
        data: {ev_id : ev_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.process == "ok")
            {
                $("#post_row"+ev_id).remove();      
            }

        }  
    });
       }
       }
```

so when call function and deleted post, the page refresh and go me to home page.

the controller is :-

```
public function deletePostInProfile() {

$this->load->model('blog');
$ev_id=intval($_POST['ev_id']);

$result = $this->blog->deletePost($ev_id);
```

}

why refresh page and go me to home page ??

Comment: you need to be a little more clear on your explanation of the issue and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the page after you deleted the post do this:

```
function delete_post( ev_id )
{
    var message_confirm =confirm("are you sure?");
    if (message_confirm==true)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "home/deletePostInProfile",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ev_id : ev_id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.process == "ok")
                {
                    $("#post_row"+ev_id).remove();
                    window.location.href = "http://your.url";
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the page reloads after you have deleted a row? And you want to stop this?

Comment: Please try to give some alerts in the success function to see where the relocation happens. Because right now, I don't see where this happens.

Comment: i will put alert `success: function(data)
  {
   alert("");
   if(data.process == "ok")
   {
    $("#post_row"+ev_id).remove();  
   }

  } ` its not display any alert so where problem

Comment: The next time you open the list, the post is deleted?

Comment: I guess this comes from the CI method. And I don't know CI in a good way... . Try to die through the method, i.e. give a die('HelloWorld'); on the first line of the method and then go step by step further. Or, if you have the possibility to debug do this, it is way easier.

Comment: the post was delete but when delete the page was refresh and i cannot use debug

Comment: In this case, please try to put a die in the deletePostInProfile Method and then go on row by row.

Comment: I think you have to change the url parameter from the ajax method. Try to open it directly in the browser and see if it works, and then give this url to the ajax method. To see if it works use again the die('Hello'); thing...

Answer (score 0):

You can reload page after successfully delete by using window.location.reload()

```
function delete_post( ev_id )
{   
    var message_confirm =confirm("are you sure?");
    if (message_confirm==true)
       {
    $.ajax({
        url: "home/deletePostInProfile",
        type: "POST",
        data: {ev_id : ev_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.process == "ok")
            {
                $("#post_row"+ev_id).remove(); 
                window.location.reload();     
            }

        }  
    });
       }
       }
```